# Replace characters in string array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have defined and populated an array called `vertices`. I am able to print the output to the JavaScript console as below:

```
["v 2.11733 0.0204144 1.0852", "v 2.12303 0.0131256 1.08902", "v 2.12307 0.0131326 1.10733" ...etc. ]
```

However I wish to remove the 'v' character from each element. I have tried using the `.replace()` function as below:

```
var x;
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    vertices[x].replace('v ', '');
}
```

Upon printing the array to the console after this code I see the same output as before, with the 'v's still present.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that calling `replace` with a string as the first parameter, you'll only replace the first instance. In this scenario, that looks like it will be fine, but in the future, if you're looking to "replace all", the first would need to be a regex, like `someString = someString.replace(/old/g, "new");` - since I usually want to do "replace all", I've just made it a habit to always use the regex syntax when calling `replace`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you just have to re-assign their value:

```
vertices[x] = vertices[x].replace('v ', '');
```

Answer (score 6):

Should be

```
vertices[x]=vertices[x].replace('v ', '');
```

Because replace *returns* value, and *doesn't change* initial string.

Answer (score 1):

```
vertices[x] = vertices[x].replace('v ', '');
```