# How to remove vowels from a list of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will remove all vowels in a list of strings in JavaScript. I know how to do this with a single string however I am having problem when I apply an array of strings. am getting an error `TypeError: strings.replace is not a function`.

```
  var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", 
  "flute", "double bass", "xylophone","piano"];                          

   string = strings.replace( /[aeiou]/g, '' );              

  console.log(string);
```

Comment: do it inside a for?

Comment: strings is a array not a individual string you need to use map or iterate through each string to do that

Comment: Check this link out, it seems to highlight your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742310/replace-characters-in-string-array-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", 
  "flute", "double bass", "xylophone","piano"];                          

   string = strings.map(x=>x.replace( /[aeiou]/g, '' ));              

  console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `map`:

```js
var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar",
  "flute", "double bass", "xylophone", "piano"
];

strings = strings.map(string => string.replace(/[aeiou]/g, ''));

console.log(strings);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate and replace each element with a given array of string.

```js
var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", "flute", "double bass", "xylophone", "piano"];

strings = strings.map(function (string) {
    return string.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '');
});

console.log(strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", 
  "flute", "double bass", "xylophone","piano"];

string = strings.filter(function(item) { return item.replace( /[aeiou]/g, '' ));

Comment: Using `Array#filter()` has the side-effect of removing any strings with only vowels from the array. Whether or not this is desired is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Using either a for loop or .map() to iterate through each string in your array and apply your method of replacing vowels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map()` to iterate through your `strings` array.

```js
var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", "flute", "double bass", "xylophone","piano"];           
var string = strings.map(x => x.replace(/[aeiou]/g, ''));
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing operation on an array of string so you have to use some loop or iterator to iterate over array and perform replace on individual item of that array. In code below I am using map function to loop and remove vowels from each index.

```
var strings = ["bongo drums", "guitar", 
 "flute", "double bass", "xylophone","piano"];      

var stringsWithOutVovels =  strings.map(function(item){
  return item.replace( /[aeiou]/g, '' ); 
});

console.log(stringsWithOutVovels);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeVowels(word){

let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
 let string = '';

   for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
     if(!vowels.includes(word[i])){
        string += word[i]
       };
      };
return string 
};

 console.log(removeVowels('Hello'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function disemvowel(str) {             
    let newString = " ";                            
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)  
{           
      if (str[i] != "a" && str[i] != "e" && str[i] != "i" && str[i] != "o" && str[i] != "u")                                   
       {           
       newString += str[i];         
      };   
    };   
    return newString;   
  };  
  console.log(disemvowel('ajmal'));
```